# How to get field's names of rawqueryset in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

I have a "rawqueryset" object that its fields can be vary in term of some business rules. How can I access to its count and name of fields in corresponding template?

View.py

```
objs=MyModel.objects.raw(sql)
return list(objs)
```

template.py

```
{%for obj in objs%}
    {{obj.?}}  
    {{obj.?}}  
    .
    ? 
{%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue using two filters:

template.py:

```
{% load my_tags %}

{%for obj in objs%}
    {%for key in obj|get_dict %}
        {% with d=obj|get_dict  %}
            {{key}} - {{ d|get_val:key }}
        {% endwith %}
    {%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

my_tags.py:

```
@register.filter(name='get_dict')
def get_dict(v):
    return v.__dict__   

@register.filter(name='get_val')
def get_val(value, arg):
    return value[arg]
```

Answer (score 0):

Must be honest, I'm not sure about the properties of a `RawQuerySet`. If it was a normal `QuerySet`, I'd try this.

```
{% for obj in objs.values %}
    {% for key, val in values.items %}
        {{ key }}: {{ val }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Does that do the trick?

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't work! As you said rawqueryset has not values properties/method.